# A 4-manifold with a special non-free circle action?

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology, 4-manifolds

Let $X$ be an oriented closed 4 manifold, with a nontrivial orientation-preserving circle action.

**Question** Is there an example such that $X/S^1$ is an orbifold (not a manifold), with a trivial first Betti number.

Comment: Out of interest, why do you ask for $X/S^1$ not to be a manifold? Do you know examples where $X/S^1$ is a manifold with $b_1(X/S^1) = 0$?

Comment: How about  X=U(2) ? @MichaelAlbanese

Comment: Fair enough. For some reason I thought you wanted $\chi(X) \neq 0$, but now I see that there is nothing in the question that indicates that.

Comment: The 3-disk (a reflective orbifold) is the orbit space of the circle action on $S^4$ induced by the inclusion $SO(2)\to SO(5)$ that factors through $SO(3)$. More generally, one can start with a desired orbit space and build circle actions on demand following "Classification of Circle Actions on 4-Manifolds" by R. Fintushel, Transactions of the American Mathematical Society Vol. 242 (1978), pp. 377-390.